# How to show HTML in Marker's description in react-native-maps?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

In `react-native-maps` Marker allows a description props which should be string. But in my use case I have a description with html tags like this `"<p>hello <strong>world</strong></p>"`. How can I show the html in Marker description? Currently It shows the whole string with tags.

I can remove the html tags using regex, but I really want the html tag's effect such as `<b><strong>` e.t.c

```
<MapView.Marker
  /*--- other props ----*/
  title={marker.name}
  description={marker.description}
>
  /*--- marker custom image ---*/
</MapView.Marker>
```

Note: I don't want to any third-party library for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html. I am not sure that it will work, but I use it for displaying HTML in the app.

Comment: I really don't want to use any third-party library only for this 

Comment: I don't believe that there is another solution.

Comment: Let's see whether someone can help or not 